# On the Normality of the Sum of Two Normal Operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, examples-counterexamples, normal-operator

It is well kown that

> **Theorem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be two normal operators. If $A$ commutes with $B$, then
>   $A + B$ is normal.

Indeed the proof follows by using the Fuglede theorem since the commutativity of $A$ and $B$ implies the commutativity of $A$ and $B^*$.

> The converse of this theorem is not always true. I hope to construct
>   a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take, for instance,$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$These matrices are normal and they don't commute, but $A+B$ is still normal. Actually, it's symmetric.